# How can I get Heroku to detect buildpack?

Tags: python, git, heroku, pyramid

I am trying to deploy my Pyramid app on Heroku and no matter what I do, I get the failed to detect buildpack error message after I try to push.

I have my requirements.txt from my pip freeze in there next to my setup.py as well as my Procfile and runapp.py. I am not using my master branch for Heroku and have been using

```
git push heroku local_branch:master
```

I have also tried to set the build pack manually by using

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

I also have tried using external buildpacks from github, but that also does not work. I must be missing something in my requirements.txt?

Also, I have read Pyramid's Docs on Heroku deployment as well as Heroku's. I have browsed here for help but all I can find is that to make sure requirements.txt is spelled correctly or just re-init my git.

Comment: What errors do you get when you set a build pack manually and push to heroku?

Comment: remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/python
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/python

Comment: I'm surprised about the problems you are having. I never need to set a build pack for a python application. What's the directory structure of your application?

Comment: Repo Root with license and readme/directory with setup.py and heroku required files/ app files

Comment: And you have a procfile? What's in it?

Comment: @FlegD, this might have changed but Heroku used to insist that files it cares about (e.g. `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`) be in the root of your repository. It sounds like yours are in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

Add a "requirements.txt" file to the root directory of your repository.